# gethostbyname return ip of non existing host

Tags: c++, host, gethostbyname

I use gethostbyname and pass the string "10.33" to the function. This host does not exist:

```
host 10.33
Host 10.33 not found: 3 (NXDOMAIN)
```

However, gethostbyname returns the following:

```
phostent = gethostbyname ("10.33");
inet_ntoa (* (struct in_addr *) phostent-> h_addr_list [0]): 10.0.0.33>
```

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the behavior

Comment: `10.33` is a perfectly valid numeric hostname. The `host(1)` command is wrong here, although `33.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa` is also not found anyway, which is what would be looked up if it weren't abbreviated.

Comment: the command is called gethostbyname. I put in a name of an none existing host. I would think that than the command tells me that the host is not existing. Right ?